# Domain of a multiple logarithmic function.

Tags: calculus, functions, logarithms

Find the domain of the following function:

**$f\left(x\right)=log_4\left(log_5\left(log_3\left(18x-x^2-77\right)\right)\right)$**

My text provides a solution which goes like:

=> $log_5\left(log_3\left(18x-x^2-77\right)\right)>0$

=> $log_5\left(log_3\left(18x-x^2-77\right)\right)>log_51$

=> $log_3\left(18x-x^2-77\right)>1$

=> $log_3\left(18x-x^2-77\right)>log_33$

=> $18x-x^2-77>3$

=> $\left(x-8\right)\left(x-10\right)<0$

=> $8<x<10$ (Answer)

But what about

$log_3\left(18x-x^2-77\right)>0$ and $18x-x^2-77>0$.

Shouldn't we consider the above inequalities?

Answer (score 1):

$$log_3\left(18x-x^2-77\right)>log_33\text{ and }log_33>0 \implies log_3\left(18x-x^2-77\right)>0$$
Also
$$18x-x^2-77>3\implies 18x-x^2-77>0$$

Comment: Of course yes, I know that, but my text doesn't mention this inequality. It ends the solution with the former inequality. So is the text wrong? Should we consider the latter one?